# How can I use CUDA only CPU?

Tags: macos, cuda, gpu, cpu

My Mac book Pro has "Intel Iris Graphics 6100" and it's not supported by CUDA. Therefore, I'd like to use only CPU version of CUDA, but I can not find that in official website. Isn't is supported anymore?

Comment: This answer may be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946701/compile-cuda-code-for-cpu).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any (official) CPU version of CUDA supported by NVIDIA, however, there's other projects such as [gpuocelot](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gpuocelot/) which attempts to address the problem. In their own words:

> Ocelot currently allows CUDA programs to be executed on NVIDIA GPUs,
>   AMD GPUs, and x86-CPUs at full speed without recompilation.

*(I've not tried it though)*