# Ubuntu 14.04 how to install cuda 6.5 without installing nvidia driver

Tags: graphics, cuda, driver, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on workstation with CPU core I7 4790 and two GPUs GTX 760 4 GB ram/1152 core the system's memory is 16 GB RAM I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS after many tries and reinstalling Ubuntu many times finally i have correctly installed nvidia driver 340.46 using 3 shell commands ppa xorg-edgers

now i want to install Cuda 6.5 toolkit
but in the manual they say that the cuda toolkit installer will also install nvidia Graphics driver

how to prevent the installer from reinstall the graphics driver how to install cuda 6.5 toolkit without reinstalling my graphics driver because i faced many problems until i installed 340.46 correctly

and after successfully installing cuda toolkit 6.5 how to upgrade my graphics driver without disturbing cuda toolkit and reinstall everything from the beginning

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you use the [runfile installer method](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile), the toolkit installer will prompt you individually for each of the 3 components:

1. GPU Driver
2. CUDA Toolkit
3. CUDA Samples

So use the runfile installer method, and simply select "no" to the first prompt, if you don't want to install the driver.  You can still install the toolkit and samples.  You can download the runfile installer from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)

> and after successfully installing cuda toolkit 6.5 how to upgrade my graphics driver without disturbing cuda toolkit and reinstall everything from the beginning

The driver can always be installed separately by downloading a driver installer package from www.nvidia.com.

If you use a package manager method, it should be possible to install the toolkit without the driver by installing the **cuda-toolkit-X.Y** package, where X.Y is the CUDA version.  Refer to [the package manager section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-additional) of the install guide

Comment: Yeah that is perfect and also  using nvidia repo .deb  after you have installed nvidia 340.58    will not install the driver  i have watched the installation process on the shell it didn't install nvidia-340.58 driver  it installed only nvidia-340-dev     not the driver itself and installed the toolkit and the samples  thank you for  your answer

Comment: @BelalMedhat I've found that the CUDA toolkit does not always have the latest version of the drivers packaged with it. So, its best to get the latest drivers separately before going ahead with the installation process

Comment: @Gokul_uf Thank you for your comment, Yes it's better to first install latest driver and then install CUDA toolkit, on Linux I think CUDA installation script download latest drivers from Ubuntu repositories, but sometimes problems happen, it's better to first install latest driver, in CUDA installation if you installed a Nvidia driver, it will not install new driver, it will install the rest of libraries and tools, Thank you again.

Comment: For my setting,  Ubuntu 18.04, CUDA 10.2, for example, running `sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-10-2` works for me. It installs the desired packages wrapped inside the toolkit without installing the driver, saving many conflicts and hassle.

Comment: @carusyte Thank you so much for this.  I was having the worst time trying to get cuda 11.0 installed instead of 11.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.  11.2 wouldn't work with Tensorflow 2.4, and the 11.0 install would crash and ruin my driver install.  Nowhere in the documentation could I find how to do this.  I just ran sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-11-0 instead of sudo apt-get install cuda (as per documentation) and it worked.  Thanks again!